# WordPress custom post automatically generating <strong> element that breaks my design

Tags: wordpress, generate

I have designed a custom wordpress website. After publishing a custom post I see the design is broken. After checking inspect element, I saw  element is automatically generating and its breaking my design. I don't know how and from where its coming. Can anyone help me to figure out this issue.

Thanks,
Gazi

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. I made a custom function for an excerpt. That was the issue. I didn't stripe the html tags. So, it was generating  tag.